# SwiftUI buttons not tappable when presented from UIKit

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, uikit

Seeing some weird issue with a swiftUIView where button taps are no longer working when presented from a UIKit controller. Basically presenting it from a navigationItem, the swiftUIView populates fine but none of the buttons are tappable. Currently testing this on the simulator

```
let settingsButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: nil, image: UIImage(systemName: "gearshape"), primaryAction: UIAction(handler: { [weak self] _ in
    guard let self = self else { return }
    let controller = UIHostingController(rootView: SettingsView(storeManager: self.storeManager))
    self.navigationController?.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
}))
```

Comment: "but none of the buttons are tappable" What buttons? There are no buttons in the code you've shown.

Comment: @mn1 pls add more details in your question.

Comment: nvm I figured out, why it wasn't working. I had disable set to `MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail()` which disabled all actions on simulator.